# When iOS shrinks an image, does it clip/pixelate it?

Tags: ios, image, clip, shrink, pixelate

I have 2 relatively small pngs that will be images inside `UIButton`s.

Once our app is finished, we might want to resize the buttons and make them smaller.

Now, we can easily do this by resizing the button frame; the system automatically re-sizes the images smaller.

**Would the system's autoresize cause the image to look ugly after *shrinking* the image?** (i.e., would it clip pixels and make it look less smooth than if I were to shrink it in a photo editor myself?)

Or would it better to make the image the sizes they are intended to be?

Comment: I believe Apple's advice is to have separate images for each known size (provided they're discrete sizes, which sounds like the case here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to make the images of correct size from the beginning. All resize-functions will have negative impact on the end result. If you scale it up to a larger image it will be a big different, but even if you scale it down to a smaller it is usually creating visible noise in the image. Let's say that you have a line of one pixel in your image. scale it down to 90% of the original size, this line will just use 90% of a pixel wide and other parts of the images will influence the colors of the same pixels.